# PHP log in system using xml

Tags: php

I am new to php and xml. I am trying to build a php login system using xml file but it is not working. I am trying to just verify username but it is not showing anything in the form page.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
   $n=$_POST['username'];
   $p=$_POST['password'];
   //echo $n;
   $xml1=simplexml_load_file("user.xml");
   if($xml1->username==$n)
   {
    echo 'Yahoo';
   } 
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="username"/><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="login" name="login"/>
</form>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE userlist[
<!ELEMENT userlist (user*)>
<!ELEMENT user (username,password)> 
<!ELEMENT username (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT password (#PCDATA)>
]>

<userlist>
  <user>
  <username>ratan</username>
  <password>1234</password>
  </user>
</userlist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should retrieve the `user` entry:

```
$xml1=simplexml_load_file("user.xml");
$xmlUsername = $xml1->user->username;
```

Complete example: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: This is correct, but it will return still a SimpleXMLElement, to get the string you can use `$username = $xmlUsername->__toString()` or `$username = "$xmlUsername"` or `(string) $xmlUsername` and so on... This is probably why the if check is failing, because compares $n to an object

Comment: If the node is text it's not necessary to manually do the `__toString()` as you can see in documentation example: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6433

Answer (score 0):

you may not have the php xml library installed...

```
sudo apt-get install php-7.0-xml
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```